# Recursive linked list in C

Tags: c, recursion, linked-list

I've just tried to implement a recursive linked list append in C, and for some reason l keeps being NULL no matter what I do, even though I malloc when encountering a NULL value.

The following code prints nothing. Any ideas?

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>

typedef struct node {
  unsigned v;
  struct node* next;
} node;

void insert(unsigned x, node* l) {
  if (l == NULL){
    node* new_node = (node*)malloc(sizeof(node));
    new_node->v = x;
    new_node->next = NULL;
    l = new_node;
  }
  else {
    insert(x, l->next);
  }
}

void print(node *l) {
  if (l == NULL) return;
  printf("%d\n", l->v);
  print(l->next);
}

int main(){

  node* l = NULL;
  insert(1, l);
  insert(2, l);

  print(l);

  return 0;
}
```

Help much appreciated.

EDIT: Even if I initialize it, it's still the same.

Comment: `l` is uninitialized.

Comment: You never pointed `l` at anything - you were (un)lucky if it was null, because it's an uninitialized pointer.  You'll also have problems with the `insert()` function that doesn't protect against trying to re-insert a node that's already contained in a list.

Comment: `l = new_node;` does not do what you think it does - you'd need to pass in a pointer to a pointer as argument (`node** l`) and assign `*l = new_node;`

Comment: @UnholySheep Dear god ... thank you man. I wasted 3 hours of my life on this. May I ask what exactly was the problem with the old code .. I still don't understand why it didn't work.

Comment: Having `node* l` as a parameter means that your function has a local pointer variable that points to the same address as the pointer you pass in. However changing what it points to (via `l = new_node;`) only changes what the pointer inside the function points to, it does not affect the one you passed as a parameter. - that's why you need a pointer to  a pointer

Comment: Ahhhh ... makes sense. Thanks :)

Comment: This must be a duplicate of hundreds if not thousands of "cannot get a linked list insert function to work properly" questions.  There are two solutions — the one mentioned in the comments so far, and 'return the new head node from the insert function' (`list = insert(list, new_value);`).  Both work; there isn't a lot to choose between them.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>

typedef struct node {
unsigned v;
struct node* next;
} node;

node* insert(unsigned x, node** ll) {
  if (*ll == NULL){
*ll = (node*)malloc(sizeof(node));
(*ll)->v = x;
(*ll)->next = NULL;

  }
  else {
    insert(x, &(*ll)->next);
}
}

void print(node *l) {if (l == NULL) return;
printf("%d\n", l->v);
print(l->next);
}

int main(){

node* l = NULL;
insert(1, &l);
insert(2, &l);
print(l);

return 0;
}
```

compiled with no gcc no switches

output:
1
2

Answer (score 0):

First off, you're passing l to your function by value so you won't see any changes made to it. Currently, when you set l to new_node, you only change the local value of l in the method insert. You may want to modify your function to return l and set l in your main to the return value of this function.

```
node *insert(int x, node *l){
  //.... your method
  return l;
}
```

In main:

```
node *l = NULL;
l = insert(1, l);
l = insert(2, l);
```

Second, your recursive call will not append nodes to your LL for the same reason. Change that call to this:

```
 l->next = insert(x, l);
```

Comment: Thanks, this solution seems to work as well. I just wanted my insert to be of type void, and not return a pointer as well. In that case a double pointer is required, right?